# vertical align bottom image on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to create an image inside a div (col-sm-4 three times).
i try to use vertical align bottom on the image but its doesnt work.
but its seem it didnt work.
the img still doest go to bottom 
my css is like this.

```
.initiative-buttons-content-inner{
  min-height: 180px;
  position: relative;
}
img{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

here the link https://jsfiddle.net/2z4czqhu/

doesany one know why it didnt work?

Answer (score 1):

Make like this

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2z4czqhu/1/

Read this
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/